# How do I secure mixed content resources in Java EE 6?

Tags: security, java-ee-6

I'm trying to decide how to secure a modern web application. I am relatively new to the Java EE 6 technology stack, but I've done some pet projects that didn't utilize security, so I'm looking for some general guidance on what's even possible using out of the box Java EE 6 security.

I understand that declarative security allows you to protect resources based on what role(s) have been assigned to a user attempting to access that resource. So, for example, a user requests a page at a particular URL, the Java EE server checks the user's credentials to see if they're authorized to access that page. This makes perfect sense for resources that only to be accessed by authenticated users. Good examples include administration pages, user account setting pages, restricted content areas.

So as long as I divide a website into secure and unsecured areas, that works fine and I have no questions. But how do I deal with the situation where I have a resource that I want to behave differently based on the authentication level of the user for declarative security.

For example, I may have a home page on a website that displays one view with a login prompt if the user is an unauthenticated user, but if an authenticated user visits that same resource should display some sort of control panel with account management links, etc instead of the login prompt.

How is this achieved in modern Java EE 6 applications? Declarative security doesn't seem expressive enough to allow this to happen as it's very "all or nothing". I've read a little about programmatic security, but all the guides talk about servlets and in a modern web application I would assume that JSFs would be the way to go, not raw servlets. I want to ensure that when I secure a web application with this mixed content that depends on the authentication status of the user that I don't end up spamming security code all throughout the web app because that's extremely error prone, and very messy.

Given the above requirements what solutions would you recommend? I'm not looking for a step by step, just some helpful pointers to get me started in the right direction. Both "Here's what you can use" and "here's how it's going to fulfill your goals" would be helpful!

One last thing, I'd like to avoid loading the Spring suite onto this webapp. I like using the Java EE 6 container technologies as much as possible, and I've heard there are issues making Spring managed beans and Java EE container managed beans available to each others' contexts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you should read: the [Security](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gijrp.html) chapter of the Java ee tutorial.

In a nutshell, either in servlets or EJBs you should:

- Declare the security roles involved: `@DeclareRoles("javaee6user")`
- In your servlets either

  - use @ServletSecurity(@HttpConstraint(rolesAllowed = {"javaee6user"})) for the whole servlet *(declarative security)*
  - in the servlet's methods check with `request.isUserInRole("javaee6user")` just as you did in 'old' servlets *(programmatic security)*
- In your EJBs either

  - declare the role(s) allowed for a whole method with `@RolesAllowed("javaee6user")` *(declarative security)*
  - inject with `@Resource SessionContext ctx;` the bean context, and invoke `ctx.isCallerInRole("javaee6user")` inside your method, just as you did in 'old' EJBs *(programmatic security)*

Comment: So the JSF servelet acts a front controller for all web requests to a JSF resource mapped to the JSF servlet in the web.xml (*.xhtml for example). Obviously I haven't implemented the JSF servlet, so where would I use these pieces of security you've mentioned if I want the JSF to react differently depending on a user's authentication (display element A instead of element B on the same page).